# Strange Number Conversion C++

Tags: c++, numbers, long-integer

So I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    array<long, 3> test_vars = { 121, 319225, 15241383936 };
    for (long test_var : test_vars) {
        cout << test_var << endl;
    }
}
```

In Visual Studio I get this output:

1. 121
2. 319225
3. -1938485248

The same code executed on the website cpp.sh gave the following output:

1. 121
2. 319225
3. 15241383936

I expect the output to be like the one from cpp.sh. I don't understand the output from Visual Studio. It's probably something simple; but I'd appreciate it nonetheless if someone could tell me what's wrong. It's has become a real source of annoyance to me.

Comment: `long` is not guaranteed to be 8-bytes long (and, typically isn't, if one isn't compiling x64 application). And signed integer overflow is undefined behavior.

Comment: google integer overflow, the standard does not specify how many bytes "long" really has

Comment: `long int` is not guaranteed to have any particular length. It seems that locally `long` is different length than at whatever remote server you were using. Use [fixed width integer types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) (or `long long`, but this is not guaranteed length either).

Comment: On 64-bit systems the Visual Studio C++ compiler still have 32-bit `long` type, while GCC and Clang (whichever is used on cpp.sh) uses 64-bit `long`.

Comment: As mentioned by several people, `long` does not have a guaranteed size. You can demonstrate the problem by printing `sizeof(long)` on each platform, which will show you a different number of bytes (most likely 4 and 8). You can also print [`std::numeric_limits<long>::max()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max) to see the largest value this type can contain on any given platform. You might want to swap `long` for [`int64_t` or `int_least64_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer).

Comment: Oh, and don't forget `l` or `ll` literal (unsigned counterparts `ul` and `ull`), or the compiler will interpret the literal value as `int`

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Without a suffix, the type of an integer literal is the smallest of (`int`, `long int`, `long long int`) in which it fits.

Comment: @molbdnilo Didn't know that, thanks :)

Comment: I usually write those suffixes in caps `L`, `LL`, `UL` and `ULL` as it stands out more, visually. That way, the letter `l` won’t be confused for the number `1`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The MSVC uses a 4Byte `long`. The C++ standard only guarantees `long` to be at least as large as `int`. Therefore the max number representable by a `signed long` is `2.147.483.647`. What you input is too large to hold by the `long` and you will have to use a larger datatype with at least 64bit.

The other compiler used a 64bit wide `long` which is the reason why it worked there.

You could use `int64_t` which is defined in [`cstdint` header](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer). Which would guarantee the 64bit size of the signed int.

Your program would read:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    array<int64_t, 3> test_vars = { 121, 319225, 15241383936 };
    for (int64_t test_var : test_vars) {
        cout << test_var << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: You also have to use `int64_t` in the for loop, else it will print the same.

Comment: @AlexanderDaum Oh, doh. Thanks.